# Why do some Beta sites does not contain the tag Beta

Tags: discussion

Consider [this](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481?phase=definition) AI site. It is in Beta stage only. But when you open the [main site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), it does not show Beta after the name.

The case of some sites including ours is different. It shows beta in main site also.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

I asked this on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) here: [Are the 'Quantum Computing' and 'Artificial Intelligence' sites still in Beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352737/313042).

According to [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352738/313042), the lack of a Beta label on the [AI site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is most likely because  the site had a sponsorship. There are other sites like this as well, and the details are covered in the Meta question and answer.

See these posts on Meta SE for which sites have had sponsors and what a sponsorship entails:

- [Which Stack Exchange sites have dedicated sponsors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341662/313042)
- [Site Sponsorships — Bringing Resources BACK to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307861/313042)